# KDB/q How to use Union Join (notation question)

Tags: join, union, kdb, union-join

I've been trying to union join these two tables for about an hour now and am seceding to StackOverflow to help me.

I have one table that looks like this:
FIRST_TABLE:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | Items | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | 2:35 | 5:00 | 12 | Q2 |
| Bob | 3:15 | 4:40 | 20 | A7 |

And another like this:
SECOND_TABLE:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | ID | Marker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sue | 1:35 | 4:00 | U5 | Outside_Time_Period |
| Ray | 9:15 | 9:40 | Y8 | Outside_Time_Period |

I'm trying to union join so that it looks like this, with any unmatched items as null:

| Name | Start Time | End Time | Items | ID | Marker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May | 2:35 | 5:00 | 12 | Q2 |  |
| Bob | 3:15 | 4:40 | 20 | A7 |  |
| Sue | 1:35 | 4:00 |  | U5 | Outside_Time_Period |
| Ray | 9:15 | 9:40 |  | Y8 | Outside_Time_Period |

So far I've tried the normal join and using indices (like 3!FIRST_TABLE uj 3!SECOND_TABLE), but I get an 'nyi error, which I don't recognize.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

Please include kdb table code with your questions so it is quicker to reproduce i.e.

```
t:([]Name:`May`Bob;StartTime:02:35 03:15;EndTime:05:00 04:40;Items:12 20;ID:`Q2`A7)
t2:([]Name:`Sue`Ray;StartTime:01:35 09:15;EndTime:04:00 09:40;ID:`U5`Y8;Marker:2#`Outside_Time_Period)
```

For your desired output, `uj` without the keys achieves this:

```
t uj t2
Name StartTime EndTime Items ID Marker
---------------------------------------------------
May  02:35     05:00   12    Q2
Bob  03:15     04:40   20    A7
Sue  01:35     04:00         U5 Outside_Time_Period
Ray  09:15     09:40         Y8 Outside_Time_Period
```

You are getting `'nyi` because brackets are missing for the first table:

```
3!t uj 3!t2
'nyi
```

Both tables need to be keyed:

```
(3!t) uj 3!t2
Name StartTime EndTime| Items ID Marker
----------------------| ----------------------------
May  02:35     05:00  | 12    Q2
Bob  03:15     04:40  | 20    A7
Sue  01:35     04:00  |       U5 Outside_Time_Period
Ray  09:15     09:40  |       Y8 Outside_Time_Period
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/uj/